When "pip install github", it errors with "aiohttp/_websocket.c:198:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found"
When I pip install github, I have the following error
Collecting github
  Using cached github-1.2.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Collecting aiohttp==3.8.1 (from github)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.8.1.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from github) (4.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from aiohttp==3.8.1->github) (23.1.0)
Collecting charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 (from aiohttp==3.8.1->github)
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from aiohttp==3.8.1->github) (6.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from aiohttp==3.8.1->github) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from aiohttp==3.8.1->github) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from aiohttp==3.8.1->github) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from aiohttp==3.8.1->github) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp==3.8.1->github) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: propcache>=0.2.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp==3.8.1->github) (0.2.0)
Using cached github-1.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Using cached charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp
  Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [104 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_ws.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/worker.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/multipart.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_response.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_ws.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/test_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/tracing.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_middlewares.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_app.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/streams.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_protocol.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/log.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_request.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_websocket.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_proto.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/locks.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_server.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/base_protocol.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/payload.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_reqrep.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_log.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/resolver.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/formdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/payload_streamer.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_routedef.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/connector.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/typedefs.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/hdrs.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_fileresponse.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_writer.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/tcp_helpers.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/helpers.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/cookiejar.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/pytest_plugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/abc.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      running egg_info
      writing aiohttp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp/*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying aiohttp/_cparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_find_header.c -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_find_header.h -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_find_header.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_headers.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.c -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_parser.c -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_parser.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_writer.c -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_writer.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_websocket.c -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_websocket.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      creating build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_cparser.pxd.hash -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_find_header.pxd.hash -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_helpers.pyi.hash -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_helpers.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_http_parser.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_http_writer.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_websocket.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/hdrs.py.hash -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/.hash
      running build_ext
      building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c aiohttp/_websocket.c -o build/temp.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/aiohttp/_websocket.o
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:198:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
        #include "longintrepr.h"
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (aiohttp)

My Python version is Python 3.13.0
I tried pip uninstall aiohttp and reinstall it using pip install aiohttp, it seems all good. But somehow, when pip install github, will fail.
Is this a python issue, or my machine issue?

Please check if  you have the necessary build tools and dependencies for compiling Python packages on macOS. These include cmake,pkg-config,openssl

github requires a specific minimum version of aiohttp which is not compatible with Python 3.11+. Try to install the newest version of aiohttp manually first or an older Python version.

This thread covers a discussion about this
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/8194
